# Where can I find "System properties settings"?

Tags: menu, system

I can't find System properties settings, how can I set it?

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "System properties settings"?

Answer (score 4):

Go to System/Administration and choose "System Monitor". You will see the "System Properties" by clicking the "System" Tab.

A screenshot is placed here for you to see what I mean. I hope this is what you wish.

[image]